# MIST - How to send all coins in account

Tags: ether, accounts, mist, balances

Mist shows that I have 1 ETH in my account. When I check etherscan see exactly 0.99895 ether in my account....

I would like to send all 0.99895 ether to another address. When I try to send exactly that amount, I get an error saying not enough funds.

MIST also shows me "0.00105 ETHER FEE". When I deduct that from the total (try to send 0.99790) it also tell me not enough funds.

How on earth do I sent this entire amount? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In order to send Ether, you need to pay a transaction fee of 21k gas (more if you are sending to or from a contract-based wallet).

Mist rounds some Ether values, so it is very difficult to send exactly the amount in your wallet. To send roughly the amount you want, just lower the transaction value by 0.0001 ETH or so, or reduce the transaction fee by sliding the "select fee" slider left.

If you really want precision, you can use the command line client that is packaged with Mist. Open up your command line, and `cd` into the `./resources/node/geth/` directory. Then run

`./geth --exec "eth.sendTransaction({from:'0xADDRESS',to:'0xRECIPIENT',value:eth.getBalance('0xADDRESS')-21000*50000000000-1,gas:21000,gasPrice:50000000000})" --unlock '0xADDRESS' console`

Replace both instances of ADDRESS and RECIPIENT with your address and the recipient's address respectively. Leave the quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm most of the way there. I'm on Windows 10 for starters. I ran the command and received an error: Invalid ' '0xADDRESS' ' - It shows two quotation marks at each end just like I have copied here....

Comment: Did you replace ADDRESS with your address? And made sure to copy it correctly?

Comment: Yes, and I get this exact error: Fatal: Invalid account address ''0xADDRESS'' - accept I have copied my exact address out of MIST.

Comment: I don't think you replaced all instances of ADDRESS. I edited the code, so now you just need to replace ADDRESS twice and RECIPIENT once. Keep the '0x' in front.

Comment: What you pasted resulted in the same error. However, I removed the " around the ADDRESS for the unlock flag, I got it to prompt me for my passphrase. After successful unlock I got this error: http://pastebin.com/raw/XJLxEUMN

Comment: Could you post exactly what you are entering? Or just give me the two addresses and I can format the command for you.