# Why is my TX failing due to lack of gas even though the correct amount of gas was supplied?

Tags: transactions, gas, contract-invocation, out-of-gas

Caveat: I tried to provide links to my transactions and addresses in etherscan.io, but I "need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."

I have an account that I want to sweep. I want to sweep the ETH to a funds splitting contract (ETC/ETH). I'm only interested in sweeping the ETH balance and my goal is for the account to end up with a balance of zero (e.g. no dust).

This is the fund splitting contract I'm trying to use: [0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0](http://etherscan.io/address/0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0#code)

It seems as if the gas required for this operation is 29,717. For example, here is a sample transaction I sent to the contract, which according to etherscan.io required that amount of gas: [0x7cd52325c0945d0de975a6713abdc50659c0c62ef523a1a99f2ad2a2d4128a8f](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x7cd52325c0945d0de975a6713abdc50659c0c62ef523a1a99f2ad2a2d4128a8f)

However, if I send a transaction and limit the amount of gas to 29,717, my transaction fails. For example, here is a sample transaction I sent to the contract with a gas limit of 29,717, which failed due to lack of gas: `0xcd31481b4dd9410daa22c8a47f9a4b29ef4a305877174eb346433bb4e6b03089` (TX)

I discovered the minimum amount of gas that I need to specify for one of these transfers to work is 31,991:

- Transaction with 31,991 gas which worked: `0x7cd52325c0945d0de975a6713abdc50659c0c62ef523a1a99f2ad2a2d4128a8f` (TX)
- Transaction with 31,990 gas which failed: `0x8c92fde3cf07b3cdbf4dcc54ed6ccfb072f22933ab556612f3d23317a2466280` (TX)

However, when the tx goes through, it seems as if it only used 29,717 gas. For example:
Account `0x19d90f1106c600bd8a70b5775776b4ecdc7a945b` (address) had a balance of `0.01282711 ETH` (at block `1964300`).

I sent transaction `0xb57c8b5aede3070e2fb80ea9a21ec43293cb5c7392ccb36357388422e9055509` (TX) with the following details:

- Value: `0.01218729 ETH`
- Gas: `31991`
- Gas Price: `20000000000 Wei`

So:

- Balance before TX: `0.01282711 ETH`
- Amount to send: `0.01218729 ETH`
- Supposed cost of TX: `Gas` * `Price` = `0.00063982 ETH`
- Balance - Amount to send - Supposed cost of TX = *ZERO!*

However, as you can see, account `0x19d90f1106c600bd8a70b5775776b4ecdc7a945b` (address) has a balance of `0.00004548 ETH`.

This in turn means that the actual cost of the TX was `0.00059434 ETH`: Actual Cost of TX = Balance before TX - Amount sent - Actual End Balance = 0.01282711 - 0.01218729 - 0.00004548 = 0.00059434.

At a gas price of `20000000000 Wei`, this means the amount of gas used was: `29717` (0.00059434/0.00000002 = 29717)

So the question are:

1. Why are the transactions which specify a gas limit of `29717` failing?
2. How do I sweep the funds so the ending balance of an ETH account is zero when using the contract above?

### System information

Geth version: 1.4.10-stable-c2eea630
OS & Version: Linux

### Expected behaviour

Transaction 0x19d90f1106c600bd8a70b5775776b4ecdc7a945b should've been successful.

### Actual behaviour

Transaction 0x19d90f1106c600bd8a70b5775776b4ecdc7a945b failed due to lack of gas.

### Steps to reproduce the behaviour

Use the `transfer(address)` function of contract `0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0` by sending some amount and limit the amount of gas to `29717`

Here is a sample transaction to this contract you can send via the JSON-RPC API:
`'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0xe7c7d161800ebb5112d7d892510e9f1dafc4010c","to":"0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0","value":"0x1F99A58657EED0","data":"0x1a69523000000000000000000000000029d5527caa78f1946a409fa6acaf14a0a4a0274b"}],"id":6}'`

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/how-to-transfer-the-whole-balance-of-an-account

Answer (score 7):

Understanding this puzzle can be instructive.
The behavior can be explained by the way the `CALL` instruction works in terms of gas.

We can compare the transactions VM traces here:

- OK: https://live.ether.camp/transaction/7cd52325c0945d/vmtrace#65
- KO: https://live.ether.camp/transaction/cd31481b4dd941/vmtrace#65

(Links are to program counter just before the failing `CALL`).

Let's consider both transactions in parallel, `A` will be the successful transaction and `B` the failed one. The value is the remaining gas at any step.

1. Contract call: `A = 31991`, `B = 29717`.
2. Before the contract even start, `22680` are consumed. `A = 9311`, `B = 7037`.
3. A number of instructions are performed that have a cumulative cost of `271`.
4. Before the actual transfer `CALL`, at step 65, we are thus at `A = 9040`, `B = 6766`.
5. At that point `B` fails because it doesn't have enough gas to perform the `CALL` instruction, which cost `9040 gas`.
6. After the call though, the `9040 gas` haven't been entirely consumed in `A`: we are back at `2300`.
7. `A` continues its operations until the last instruction where it sits at `2274`.
8. The unused `2274` are refunded and the total gas consumed is indeed `31991-2274 = 29717`.

There are two points that explain the surprising behavior.

- The cost of a value-transferring CALL is 40 + 9000. (per [Yellow Paper appendix G](http://gavwood.com/Paper.pdf)).
- **An amount of 2300 gas is taken from this cost and forwarded to the recipient as gas**.

The second point is the key. In the context of a contract calling another contract, this so-called `stipend` is provided as minimal gas to cover operational costs of a basic fallback function. Note that it is also possible to manually forward more gas if it is known that the recipient has larger needs.

In our case, since the recipient account is not a contract, the `stipend` was refunded. In a sense the `CALL` operation cost was only `6740 gas` but we had to show that we had at least `9040` to cover the case of a contract callee.

In previous versions the entire gas of the caller was forwarded to the callee, but this was open to abuse and the new behavior was put into place.

More linkies:

- [Fallback functions and the fundamental limitations of using send() in Ethereum & Solidity](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Ethereum-Development-Best-Practices/wiki/Fallback-functions-and-the-fundamental-limitations-of-using-send%28%29-in-Ethereum-&-Solidity)
- [King of the Ether postmortem](http://www.kingoftheether.com/postmortem.html)