# Node script to sweep accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, wallets

I have a rather large list of accounts (HD wallets) I want to sweep into one.

They've all been imported into geth, and all have the same password.

I wrote a script to do this in node but get this error:

```
Error: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Here is the node script:

```
//web3
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

//starting index... main account is 0... don't sweep that one ^.^
var startSweep = 1;

//account shell
var accounts = [];

//transaction cost... i think?
var gas = 21000;

//geth stuff
var sys = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) };

//connect to node
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

//get accounts
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

//set default account for gas
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

//loop through accounts and sweep balances
for(var x = startSweep; x<accounts.length; x++){
    //get current account balance
    var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[x]);

    //if balance is greater than 0 lets transfer... 
    if(balance > gas){
        //command to unlock account 
        var execCommand = 'geth --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts['+x+'], \'password\', 1000)" attach';
        console.log(execCommand);

        //execute command
        exec(execCommand, puts);
        console.log(' Unlocked account ' + accounts[x] + ' with a balance of ' + balance + '! ' + 'TRANSFERING!');
        var transaction = {
            "to" : accounts[0],
            "from" : accounts[x],
            "value" : balance - gas,
            "gas": gas
        };

        //send transaction
        web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log('Sent transaction from : '+ accounts[x]);
    }
}
```

I read that the cost of a transaction was 21000, but I get that error.... So I just kept bumping the gas up until I received the error:

```
Error: Exceeds block gas limit
```

So I guess I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that one or more of the accounts don't have enough in them to cover the cost of the transaction? (i.e. balance < 21000)

Comment: I'm running a test with only three accounts right now, they all have balances greater than 21000.  It is my understanding that the gas will come from the main account anyways (index 0) which has a few eth in it.  Someone please correct me if i'm wrong here though.

Comment: I may have accidently deleted your comment @RichardHorrocks. sorry!

Comment: Sorry, that was me. As per the deleted comment, you need to take into account the gas _price_, as well as the amount of gas. In which case `value: balance - (gas * gas price)`, as per http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5766/52. Also see http://ether.fund/tool/calculator

Comment: After some cowboy-esque edits I accidentally set gas to *210,000*. I reset it back to *21000* and everything works as it should.  I will update OP with the modified code in case it can help someone.  Thanks @RichardHorrocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not calculating the gas correctly.  Here is the updated code in case anyone wants to do something similar.

```
//web3
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

//starting index... main account is 0... don't sweep that one ^.^
var startSweep = 1;

//account shell
var accounts = [];

//transaction cost.
var gas = 21000;

//geth stuff
var sys = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) };

//connect to node
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

//current gas price
var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice.toNumber();

//get accounts
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

//set default account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

//loop through accounts and sweep balances
for(var x = startSweep; x<accounts.length; x++){
    //get current account balance
    var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[x]);
    //see if this is worth sending ^.^
    var balanceMinusFee = balance - (gas * gasPrice);
    if(balanceMinusFee > 0){
        //command to unlock account 
        var execCommand = 'geth --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts['+x+'], \'password\', 1000)" attach';
        console.log(execCommand);

        //execute command
        exec(execCommand, puts);
        console.log(' Unlocked account ' + accounts[x] + ' with a balance of ' + balanceMinusFee + '! ' + 'TRANSFERING!');
        var transaction = {
            "to" : accounts[0],
            "from" : accounts[x],
            "value" : balanceMinusFee,
            "gas": gas
        };

        //send transaction
        web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log('Sent transaction from : '+ accounts[x]);
    }
}
```