# Ethereum web3.eth bitcoin move equivalent?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, internal-transactions

Is there a Bitcoin "move" equivalent for Ethereum web3.eth ?

In Bitcoin:

```
move
<fromaccount> <toaccount> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment]
Move from one account in your wallet to another
```

(https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: Move only transfer's balance from one account to another?

Comment: In the same wallet.

Answer (score 1):

For sending value from one account to another you can use, following web3.js API call -

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})
```

Check [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) for more details on parameters available.

> If you want to transfer the complete balance of one account to another
>   then it's not directly possible.

However, there is a way which is already described in this answer -  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5766/7790

Please take a look, hope this helps.

Comment: The question asks if there is a move equivalent feature.

Comment: I clearly mentioned its not directly possible which means there is no equivalent feature. Please read before down voting any answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62296/discussion-on-answer-by-sanchit-ethereum-web3-eth-bitcoin-move-equivalent).