# Gas calculation for ether transaction?

Tags: web3js, mining, ether, gas, gas-estimate

I'm building a sort of ether exchange. Now suppose I have 2eth in my wallet, and I want to transfer all of it to any user. What value should I transfer from my 2 ethers such that gas can also be deducted from my account and my account becomes empty at the end of the transaction? 
What is the math? How do I calculate it?? If it is dependent upon the difficulty level of mining then how can my calculations co-op up with it??
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do a plain ether transfer between accounts then it costs `21,000` gas. Approximately the average gas price is `21`Gwei [now](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice) in the network, so your transaction fee is around `0,00044` ETH. So, you should have cca. `2,00044` ETH on your account.

[This](http://ethgasstation.info/calculator.php) could be useful for you to do the math taking into account the changes of the gasprice you can easily calculate here the transaction fee.

Related [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/how-to-transfer-the-whole-balance-of-an-account)

Comment: The transaction goes into pending. Nothing happens. Any reason?

Comment: First guess: increase transaction fee, second guess: if you send it to a contract address, have a look at the fallback function of the contract.

Comment: It committed after two hours(ropsten)